# How to connect Jaeger to secured Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, jaeger

My Elasticsearch cluster is secured with HTTPS and Basic Auth. I'd like to connect `jaeger-ingester` and `jaeger-query` on it.

I tried setting:

```
es.server-urls=https://elasticsearch:9200
es.tls.enabled=true
es.username=jaeger
es.password=XXXX
```

But I get:

```
{"level":"fatal","ts":1626344336.0828998,"caller":"command-line-arguments/main.go:65","msg":"Failed to init storage factory","error":"failed to create primary Elasticsearch client: health check timeout: no Elasticsearch node available","stacktrace":"main.main.func1\n\tcommand-line-arguments/main.go:65\ngithub.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute\n\tgithub.com/spf13/cobra@v0.0.7/command.go:838\ngithub.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC\n\tgithub.com/spf13/cobra@v0.0.7/command.go:943\ngithub.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute\n\tgithub.com/spf13/cobra@v0.0.7/command.go:883\nmain.main\n\tcommand-line-arguments/main.go:114\nruntime.main\n\truntime/proc.go:225"}
```

This error message is not helpful.
How can I debug storage connection initialisation?